# How do I see the file which displays username and password on apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I know you can use the following username to add a user on to apache:

```
htpasswd -c filename UserName
```

But should not there be an actual apache file containing this. All I have is a httpd.conf file, I can't find any .htaccess or .htpasswd file. Shouldn't the user details appear in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: What is the actual file name you pass in `-c filename` ?

Comment: /etc/httpd/conf/password, password is name of file

Comment: So then one of the many config files used by apache probably refers to that password file.